# Доступ к private методам

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

Как получить доступ к private методу?
C#, VS 2012.
Спасибо.
P.S. Прежнее название темы - "Unit Test для private методов"

Comment: 1. Если класс — ваш, и вам нужен доступ к методу снаружи, почему вы объявляете его приватным?
2. Если класс — не ваш, доступ к приватному методу не имеет смысла, так как он (а) не разработан для этого, (б) при следующем обновлении может исчезнуть

---
В качестве временного хака можно воспользоваться рефлексией, только не стоит включать это в production-код.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как тестрировать private и protected методы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/321346/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-private-%d0%b8-protected-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение - использовать Reflection 
например так:

```
var field = typeof(CopyItems).GetMethod(("FixRenamedPath"), BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

string targetFile = (string)field.Invoke(null, new object[] { renamedFile, relatedFile, targetDir });
```

Comment: Отличное решение. Попробуйте теперь, имея набор написанных таким образом тестов, провести какой-нибудь рефакторинг по Фаулеру типа `Rename Method` или `Introduce Parameter Object.`

Comment: @Котик: Вы бы иронию что ли красненьким выделяли.

Comment: Речь не о рефакторинге идет.
Без этого теста, обращаясь к public полям, приходилось подготавливать файлы (удалять, копировать и т.д.)
Конечно можно было скопировать метод еще куда-то или временно сделать его public.
И зачем все это? Только потому что при private методы не принято тестировать? :)
Но гораздо проще закомментировать две строки.

Comment: @Track: private-методы — это как нижнее бельё: их никому не показывают. В любой момент они имеют право быть удалены или изменены, вероломно и без объявления войны. Включение их в unit-test означает, что вы пытаетесь зафиксировать их семантику, не говоря уж о просто наличии и списке аргументов.

Comment: Ну да - я абсолютно согласен.
Но из тестов удобно тестировать. Как это ни странно.
Когда private метод протестирован, можно закоментировать строки в тесте и забыть об этом методе. 
Но тестировать именно так удобно.

Answer (score 9):

[@Track](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/11892/track) *(В коммент точно не влезло бы `:)`*

- Как речь может идти о `Unit` тестах, но при этом не идти о рефакторинге?

> - Когда девелопится какой-то продукт, у разработчика всего два возможных варианта действий — либо писать нормальный `production` код, либо писать `write-only` код, который сразу после этого летит на помойку ([`Spike`](http://www.extremeprogramming.org/rules/spike.html) в терминологии `Extreme Programming`).
> - В первом случае `Unit` тесты специфицируют поведение этого кода и **неразрывно связаны с рефакторингом,** поскольку позволяют уменьшить количество ошибок при его выполнении.
> - Во втором случае `Unit` тесты не нужны по определению.

- Если рассуждать на тему вопроса, то тестирование `private` методов бессмысленно по нескольким причинам`:`

> - Гипотетический зеленый `Unit` тест для приватного метода **не дает никаких знаний** о поведении соответствующего класса. Этот `private` метод может вообще не вызываться из `public` методов класса, а у вас добавится ненужный тест, который еще и надо поддерживать.
> - Контракты `private` методов крайне изменчивы. Сегодня, скажем, метод называется `SafelyCreateBlackBox(...)`, а завтра — `ReconstructContainerFromScratch(...)`.
> - Оно полностью противоречит концепции `TDD,` в которой дизайн продукта продиктован спецификацией его поведения в виде набора тестов. Вы же не станете начинать разработку с написания тестов на `private` методы несуществующих классов? `:)`

- То, что в какой-то момент времени вам захотелось написать тест на `private` метод, скорее всего, означает одно из двух:

> - У вас *нет тестов* и есть некоторый класс с *большим количеством ответственностей.* Вы пытаетесь убедиться в корректности его поведения "по кусочкам", например, начав с тестирования `private` методов. Правильнее в этом случае нужно понять, какое поведение ожидается от класса, заспецифицировать это поведение в тестах, использующих `public` интерфейс класса и провести рефакторинг этого класса с целью уменьшения числа его ответственностей.
> - У вас *есть тесты* и вам все еще кажется, что тестирование `private` метода — это хорошая идея. В таком случае, скорее всего, логика `private` метода неплохо укладывается в некоторую *отдельную сущность* и может быть вынесена из исходного класса. В этом случае нужно придумать название для новой сущности, специфицировать ее поведение в тестах и вынести ее из исходного класса.

Comment: Все правильно но не по теме.
Если бы вы удосужились прочитать мой коммент(на который отвечаете) полностью то поняли бы, что конкретно в этом случае проще закинуть тестирование в Test Unit.
Чтобы и дальше не было путаницы - переименовал тему.

Comment: @Котик: последний пункт с удовольствием украду для будущих дискуссий. :)

Answer (score 7):

Начнём с того, что `private`-методы не предназначены для тестирования. Они не являются частью официального "фасада" класса, они имеют право рассчитывать на выполнение инвариантов и предварительных условий, но не проверять их явно, имеют право вести себя "неправильно", будучи вызванными в не рамках установленного для них workflow.

Вы, однако, можете тестировать `internal`-методы. Они будут доступны тестирующей сборке, если вы укажете атрибут [`InternalsVisibleTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx).

Comment: Конечно покрывать тестами все private поля глупо, но иногда может пригодиться.

Comment: @Track: поля?

Comment: методы разумеется :)