# Как тестрировать private и protected методы?

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты

Как тестировать `private` и `protected` методы, может есть какие-то стандартные средства, позволяющие сделать это?
В интернете видел примеры, что подобные методы вызываются через рефлексию, или у них тупо меняют модификатор доступа на `public` на время теста.

Answer (score 22):

У класса есть интерфейс - это совокупность его открытых методов. Тем самым он подобен черному ящику - вы что-то даете на вход, внутри ящика(класса) происходят некие  таинственные процессы, а затем он выдает вам результат этих загадочных процессов.  Поэтому любому пользователю класса важно чтобы должным образом работал именно этот интерфейс, и неважно, за счет чего он работает - за счет хитрых колдунств, безупречной логики или чего-то еще. О наличии приватных методов он ничего не знает и знать не должен.  Соответственно, тестирование имеет смысл только для публичных методов. Если они работают должным образом, то и класс работает должным образом. А его внутренности - это его личное дело.

Comment: Довольно часто, открытый метод, в котором происходя какие-то сложные вещи, вызывает внутри себя приватные методы, в которых происходит черная работа. Таких приватных методов, теоритически, там может вызываться от 1 до бесконечности. Соответственно, если тестировать на прямую открытый метод можно пропустить некоторые ошибки в приватных методах, что не есть хорошо!

Comment: @sp7, если подавать нужный спектр данных на вход, то баг, скорее всего, всплывет. Другое дело, что я тоже "за" тестирование таких методов, потому что при провале теста проще увидеть, где именно происходит поломка.

*это не в контексте шарпа, а в контексте PHP, где с концепцией "класс на любой entity" бывает туговато*

Comment: @sp7: не, это какая-то странная логика. Так если тестировать любой метод, можно пропустить ошибки по невнимательности.

Единственным правильным методом тестирования является проверка выполнения ТЗ на метод. Приватные методы имеют право появляться и исчезать, они имеют право крешить программу, будучи вызванными через reflection в неподходящий момент. Вы ж не собираетесь менять тесты с каждым изменением внутренней структуры класса, правильно?

Comment: Вообще-то считается хорошей практикой тестировать любой метод.     

> Вы ж не собираетесь менять тесты с каждым изменением внутренней структуры класса, правильно?

Тест обычно пишется под конкретный метод и под его конкретное поведение, изменился метод - изменился тест. Тут мне кажется все нормально. 

А вот что мне не дает покоя, что данные приватные методы так и не протестированы остаются, хотя порой в них кроется весьма важный функционал.

Comment: Я обычно, для того чтобы "спать спокойно" и не возиться с рефлексией, на время тестирования меняю у приватных методов модификатор доступа на публичный, тестирую их. А уже потом, когда приложение написано, возвращаю все обратно. Собственно этот костыль мне не особо и нравится, но пока что-то другого, что помогло бы от него отказаться не нашел.

Comment: > на время тестирования меняю у приватных методов модификатор доступа на публичный, тестирую их.

Вот это точно не уруру. Половина всей сути тестов в том, чтобы выполнять их регулярно.

Comment: @sp7: Публичные методы не имеют права изменяться часто — на это они и публичные, ведь ими пользуются другие! За их поведение вы отвечаете перед всей программой. Поэтому и имеет смысл специфицировать их поведение, и закрепить в тестах и документации. Эта часть программы — ваш интерфейс к остальной программе, вы не хотите менять его слишком часто.

А вот приватные методы на то и приватные, что они никому не видны. поэтому вы можете менять, добавлять/удалять, менять инварианты и семантику в них в любой момент. Да у них может и вовсе не быть семантики! Соответственно и тестировать их не надо.

Comment: @sp7: Если же у вас много логики реализовано в приватных методах, и этот код имеет свой смысл — скорее всего, ваш класс делает слишком много, его надо разбить на мелкие классы, имеющие самостоятельный смысл. Если в вашем классе более ста строк, стоит задуматься.

---
Вот ещё хороший ответ по теме: http://hashcode.ru/questions/208710#208816

Comment: Согласен с ответом. Если класс становится таким сложным, что вам уже не обойтись без тестирования приватных методов, то это значит, что пора часть логики переносить в отдельный вспомогательный класс.

Comment: Есть ещё вариант воспользоваться "покрытием кода". Многие инструменты для юнит тестирования его делают. А оно покрывает все, в том числе и приватные методы. Если какой то приватный метод не покрыт (или его часть), то значит нужно улучшить тесты (или переписать класс детальнее, вынести логику, и тому подобное).

Answer (score 21):

Никак.

`private`- и `protected`-методы не принадлежат официальному «фасаду» класса, на них нет специфицированных пред- и постусловий.

Тестируйте публичные методы, на то они и публичные. Подглядывать в грязное бельё имплементации — некрасиво.

Comment: @VladD, на мой взгляд довольно категоричное суждение.

Все же часть приватных методов внутри класса (или, что мне ближе, статических функций Си  в файле, который отправляется в библиотеку) тестировать стоит.

Обычно я просто пользуюсь препроцессором (да, к шарпу или яве это точно не относится) в таком духе:

     static int f1 () { ... }
     static int f2 () { ... }
     int foo () { f1(); ... f2(); ...} // extern foo
     ...
     #ifdef TEST1
        main () { ... f1(); // check results }
     #endif
     #ifdef TEST2
        main () { ... f2(); // check ... }
     #endif


как-то так...

Comment: @avp: на мой взгляд, с C ситуация не вполне аналогична: большие, осмысленные внутренние функции есть скорее аналог внутренних _классов_, а не приватных методов.

Классы обычно разрабатываются (ну или _должны_ разрабатываться) в соответствии с [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle): у класса есть _одна_, не раскладывающаяся на более мелкие, обязанность. Если приватные методы имеют семантику, скорее всего, этот принцип нарушен и класс _чересчур_ сложен.

Comment: @VladD, в таком случае получается, что вся логика *внутреннего устройства* класса должна меняться только public методами (и ни в коим случае не private), хотя бы мы и хотели спрятать часть этой кухни.

Поясняю -- если мы захотим изменить внутреннюю реализацию класса, а тестировать можно только вызывая public, то неразумно возлагать что-то нетривиальное на принципиально не тестируемые private методы.

IMHO излишне строгий подход, проще отказаться от неудобных академических принципов.

--

А вот как *организовать* это в шарпе? 

**That is the question.**

Comment: @avp: Почему же? Логика внутреннего устройства может быть сколько угодно сложной, но эта сложность достигается не при помощи больших внутренних процедур, а при помощи композиции с другими объектами, реализующими части функциональности. Это очень похоже на unix way написания утилит: каждый класс делает маленькое задание, и их можно/нужно комбинировать.

Пример: класс может запрашивать нужные данные, когда его об этом попросят, а может и закешировать их. Как именно он делает — невидимые миру подробности реализации. Кэш, понятно, имплементируется отдельным готовым классом, а не вручную.

Comment: @VladD, я вот еще раз перечитал Ваш и @DreamChild ответы. 

Такое ощущение, что вы оба говорите о тестировании с позиции программиста, использующего некий класс, а не пишущего (и потом поддерживающего) его.

Или я ошибаюсь?

--

А что по поводу реализации путем композиции нескольких классов, так это замечательно, но только если классы, включаемые в нее, самодостаточны и часто применимы для разных задач.

Если же несколько таких классов могут использоваться только все вместе (да еще и только в рамках данной задачи), то это и будет вытаскиванием наружу нижнего белья (тоже м.б. неплохо :)).

Comment: @avp: «Зелёный» (т. е., пройденный) тест — это гарантия (насколько полная — отдельный вопрос) того, что класс работает правильно с точки зрения пользователя класса.

Пользователи класса вызывают лишь публичные методы, поэтому если даже какой-то приватный метод в каких-то условиях работает неправильно, это на самом деле **никому не интересно**. Если эта неправильная работа мешает правильной работе всего класса, тесты публичных методов должны не проходить. Если она никому не мешает, этот метод просто никому не нужен.

Comment: Да, если рассматривать тесты как milestown в цикле разработки, как индикатор готовности для выпуска *продукта*, то больше ничего и не надо.

(отсюда и оценка: тест "прошел" или "успешно" -- это когда ошибок не найдено (хотя, наверное, все-таки должно быть наоборот)).

Если же смотреть на тесты, как на инструмент, ускоряющий *отладку*, т.е. хотеть, чтобы тест максимально точно и быстро локализовал ошибку в коде, то внутренности тоже желательно охватывать тестами.

Но, это все пожелания. На самом деле все мы достаточно ленивы, что бы ...

--

комментарии здесь все равно уже кончились.

Comment: @avp: для отладки разумеется нужен отладочный код. Но он, как я понимаю, не считается тестом, и не сохраняется в репозитории. Точно так же, как в репозиторий не сохраняется отладочная печать: это лишь средство отладки кода, после того, как код отлажен, оно не нужно.

---
Угу, и у меня лимит комментариев.

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте сделать их internal и использовать аттрибут [InternalsVisibleTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Если в приватных методах достаточно большое количество логики - подумайте о выносе их в отдельный класс, в котором они будут простыми, публичными и тестируемыми.

Пример:
Надо протестировать класс построителя [навмеша](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navigation_mesh). Грубо говоря, у него на входе 3D модель местности, а на выходе 3D модель навмеша. Внутренняя логика же достаточно сложна (десятки тысяч строк кода).
Соответственно для юнит-тестирования, надо разбивать монолит на множество простых/примитивных классов (геометрические методы, построитель высот, вектора, триангуляторы и прочие) и тестировать их по отдельности юнит-тестами, и вместе - интеграционными.

Answer (score -2):

Можно создать новую публичную функцию с префиксом "test" и с теми же аргументами. Использование таких функций легко отследить. Их легко найти (и, следовательно, удалить) в нужный момент.

**Примечание**: В Python для обозначения приватности используется "__". Но там можно получить доступ даже к приватному методу, прописав этот спецификатор. Возможно, я ошибся в деталях, но суть такая.