# phpunit test public->private methods

Tags: php, phpunit

```
class User {

private function _getName() {
    return $this->getFirstName() . ' ' . $this->getLastName();
}

private function _getUserAddr() {
    return $this->getUserStreet() . ' ' . $this->getUserTown();
}

private function _getAllow () {
    $userAllowLocations = ['Kiev', 'Zhitomir', 'Dnepr', 'Moskow', 'Berlin'];
    if (in_array($this->getUserTown(), $userAllowLocations)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}   

public function getUserInfo () {
    $userName = $this->_getName();
    $userAddr = $this->_getUserAddr(); 

    if ($this->_getAllow()) {
        return ['userName' => $userName]; 
    }
    return [
        'userName' => $userName,
        'userAddr' => $userAddr,
    ]; 
}
```

}

вопрос как можно протестить метод getUserInfo из разными вариантами значений _getAllow
Ето не реальный функционал, просто для понимания накидал схемку.
Спасибо заранее за помощь.

ПС: пробовал как сдесь сделать https://jtreminio.com/2013/03/unit-testing-tutorial-part-5-mock-methods-and-overriding-constructors/ так там чуть другая ситуация. Пока не получилось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы сделать возможность тестирования разных значений `$userAllowLocations`, нужно сделать возможность устанавливать разные значения

```
<?php

class User {

    protected $userAllowLocations;

    public function setUserAllowLocations(array $userAllowLocations)
    {
        $this->userAllowLocations = $userAllowLocations;
    }

    public function getUserAllowLocations()
    {
        return $this->userAllowLocations;
    }

    private function _getAllow ()
    {
        $userAllowLocations = $this->getUserAllowLocations();
        if (in_array($this->getUserTown(), $userAllowLocations)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо за предложение изменения самого кода, да так наверно правильнее, но все таки остался вопрос как тестировать публичные методы в которых используются приватные методы.

Comment: тобиш  как нужно бы тестить getUserInfo имитируя разные варианты возврата приватных методов в нутри getUserInfo

Comment: @php_guru а всё тоже самое: меняем состояние объекта, наполняя его данными и тестируем **только публичные** методы. Например, в моём примере я знаю, что возвратит `getUserAllowLocations`, если я до этого вызову `setUserAllowLocations(['йцукен', 'фыва'])`. Это и будет моим первым тестом. Для метода `getUserInfo` у вас тоже должно быть понимание что он должен возвращать в разных состояниях объекта.

Comment: А вообще приватные методы не принято тестировать. Вот, например: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/321346/ - там про c#, но суть одна и та же

Comment: спасибо за наводочки