# Junit: Тестируют ли private методы, если да, то как?

Tags: java, тестирование, юнит-тесты, junit

Как тестировать private методы?

Comment: [Возможный дубликат](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/321346/10105).

Comment: @VladD: вполне.

Comment: @VladD, не уверен. Там C#. Решения для разных языков могут иметь свои нюансы. Конечно, ответ «тестировать не надо» можно написать в обоих случаях, но это таки не ответ на заданный вопрос.

Comment: [И ещё один](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/208710/10105).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Обычно так не делается, это считается плохой практикой. Ну то есть если метод приватный, то есть какой-то public, который его вызывает. Вот и тестируйте этот public метод, он покроет и приватный тоже. Если уж есть private методы с какой-то очень сложной, специфичной логикой, то на время тестирования можете делать public get методы, которые вызывают приватный, либо же через reflection.

**UPD**

JUnit позволяет тестировать protected методы.

Comment: А в чем смысл оставлять private метод, если есть такой же public?

Comment: Если уж очень нужно протестировать, то сделай обертку для тестов.

Comment: Обновил ответ

Answer (score 1):

Так как обычно набор тестов находится в том же пакете, что и тестируемый класс, то можно изменить видимость метода, убрав модификатор. В google guava, кажется, даже есть маркер-аннотация по этому поводу.

Answer (score 0):

Java позволяет писать много классов и реализовать функционал (нахождение файла, фильтрация списка и т.п.) в отдельных классах. Приватные методы, как правило, состоят из публичных методов и простой логики. Если в приватный метод напихивается столько, что появляется потребность его отдельно тестировать - обычно это сигнал о том, что надо проводить рефакторинг.