# Как правильно писать JUnit тесты?

Tags: java, junit

Как, например, правильно протестить тот же ArrayList? Например, метод add() - мы добавляем элемент и знаем как должен выглядеть внутренний массив, но он, как правило, объявляется private, а тестируем мы только открытые методы. Поэтому проверяем, что размер увеличился (методом size()) или знаем, что он перестал быть пустым (метод isEmpty()), но эти методы тоже нужно тестировать. Да, они слишком простые, но очепятку можно сделать где угодно.
Еще один способ - временно объявить внутренний массив открытым и все изменения этого массива проверять с помощью assertArrayEquals() итп... Но потом можно забыть закрыть уровень видимости, да и вообще, заказчику нужны работающие тесты.
Как правильно тестировать?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/380786/junit-%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-private-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA

Comment: Еще раз читайте вопрос. Я не спрашивал про тестирование приватных методов.

Comment: @Олексій Моренець вот как раз из-за проблем, озвученных вами, многие так любят тдд. Если вы пишете сначала тест, а уже под него делаете имплементацию, у вас будет уверенность, что все методы протестированы, т.к. они тестируются шаг за шагом по мере их добавления. Когда же вы покрываете тестами уже готовый код, вы неизбежно сталкиваетесь с трудностями, описанными в вопросе.

Comment: Ну, ок. Собрался я написать ArrayList. Начинаю писать тесты. С какого метода начать? size() - могу проверить только пустой список - фактически это getter для переменной size. isEmpty() - тоже могу проверить только на пустом листе. add() - как проверить, что действительно добавился элемент, если доступа к массиву нет? Итд - любой другой метод завязан на методах этого класса, которые тоже подлежат тестированию.

Comment: @Олексій Моренець Тестироваться должно поведение класса, а не его внутренняя реализация. Тестируется публичное апи - публичные методы, определяющие поведение класса. Если ваши тесты покрывают всё желаемое поведение во всех юзкейсах и со всеми граничными условиями - это значит, что ваш класс работает, как задумано. Вот это интересно заказчику, а не детали имплементации. Загуглите что-нибудь вроде "java tdd stack kata", и большинство вопросов отпадёт. Рекомедую найти видео с Дядей Бобом (Clean Code series), он очень классно на этом примере основы показывает.

Comment: И вот это видео мне очень нравится: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8u6_hctdhqI

Comment: @fromSPb, спасибо, полезные видосики! Правда, первый без звука...