# Java JUnit публичные и приватные методы

Tags: java, junit

У меня есть два метода

```
public class Main {
    public Object get() {
    ...
    return privateGet(text)
    }

    private Object privateGet(String text) {
    ...
    return object;
    }
}
```

т.е. публичный использует приватный

Мне нужно протестировать их работу.
Для этого мне в Тесте нужно переопределить публичный метод, чтоб подставить в приватные разные варианты text для проверки.

```
@Test
    public void testGet() {

        Main main = new Main() {
            @Override
            public Object get() {
                return super.privateGet(text);
            }
        };
    }
```

ну и как вы понимаете

> return super.privateGet(text);

естественно не проходит, так как ругается, что метод приватный...
Как мне правильно сделать этот тест?

Comment: Если возможно, то сделайте `privateGet(String text)`  как protected и в вашем тесте расширьте класс Main. Тогда можно будет переписать и публичный и protected методы

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Junit: Тестируют ли private методы, если да, то как?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/380786/junit-%d0%a2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%82-%d0%bb%d0%b8-private-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8b-%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba)

Comment: Только вот твой код ничечешо ни тестирует.

Comment: @Dred в данном случае, переименование в protected - подошло. Спасибо.

Comment: @RomanC ну естественно... я ж только проблемную часть привел. Сам тест тут зачем?

Comment: Что это за тест, если вы переопределяете метод в ТЕСТЕ?

Comment: @Vitaly если тест не нужен, то зачем его приводить?

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець в данном случае тестируемый метод выгребает данные из БД. А в тестовом методе, я переопределяю его, чтоб подать ему на вход тестируемые данные без подключения к БД.