# Тестирование кода уровня доступности internal

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты

Cтруктура моего проекта(solution) следующая:

project **Core** type **"Library"** - библиотека где я реализовываю базовый
функционал: например здесь у меня реализована работа с бд;

project **GUI** type **"WPF Application"** - пользовательская часть, где я планирую использовать *public* методы и функции;

project **Test** type **"Unit test project"** - здесь я занимаюсь тестированием методов и функций из ***"Core"***;

```
class Default
{
     int counter = 0;

     int groupId
     {
        get
        {
        if (!(counter < 256))
        {
            counter = 0;
        }
        counter = counter + 1;
        return counter;
        }
     }

     public void SomeMethod()
     {

     }
}
```

Подскажите возможно ли тестировать *методы/функции/свойства* которые должны быть видны только внутри ***"Core"*** (в приведенном примере это свойство groupId )если да то какой уровень доступа должен быть у такого *метода/функции/свойства* и какой уровень доступа должен быть у класса что бы он был доступен как в ***"GUI"*** так и для тестирования.

P.S.[это](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx) читал, до конца не осознал, до сих пор использовал только ***public/private*** модификаторы

**Upd.:**

Теперь я кажется понял как мне необходимо было сформулировать свой вопрос:

Мне непонятно какие уровни доступа необходимо ставить для приложений построенных описанным мной образом, т.е. есть библиотека(отдельный проект) в ней есть методы которые должны быть доступны из GUI(модификатор public), тестировать их не проблема, внутри библиотеки есть методы которые которые должны быть доступны только внутри неё, в данном случае groupId: данное свойство возвращает идентификатор для группы. я написал код, но я же должен его каким то образом протестировать, да я проверил его сделав сначала публичным написал тест посмотрел результат, изменил идентификатор удалил тест, но я подумал что это не правильно, и должен быть способ сделать это иначе (спасибо @andreycha за ответ). Так же я понял какой модификатор должен быть у Default(public спасибо @PashaPash). А причина этого вопроса была в непонимании мной понятия "сборка".

P.S.S.: спасибо всем за приведенные ссылки. Для себя решил что внутренние методы будут иметь идентификатор internal что бы была возможность их тестировать

Comment: посмотрите [Как тестрировать private и protected методы?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/321346/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-private-%d0%b8-protected-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8b)

Comment: В C# есть поля protected?

Comment: @PashaPash не дубликат. Тут речь идет о тестировании internal.

Comment: @andreycha ок, возможно. но ссылка пусть будет.

Comment: И вот ещё по теме: [Unit Test для private методов](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/208816/10105).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, возможно. `internal`-типы доступны внутри сборки, в которой они объявлены, а также в других сборках, которые указываются в файле `AssemblyInfo.cs` текущего проекта c помощью атрибута `InternalsVisibleTo`:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Test")]
```

Answer (score 4):

У не-вложенных классов (типов) есть всего два уровня доступности

- `internal`  - класс виден только внутри сборки
- `public` - класс виден откуда угодно

По умолчанию уровень доступа у класса - `internal`. Он видим только другим классам в той же сборке. Соответственно, из GUI вы не сможете получить доступ к `Default`, пока не поставите на него модификатор `public`.

Если класс не должен быть виден в GUI (например, это какой-то служебный класс сборки), но вы хотите протестировать его отдельно, то можно использовать аттрибут `InternalsVisibleTo`, который позволит видеть `internal` вещи еще из из какой-то конкретной сторонней сборки (Test), но оставит их невидимыми для GUI.

С видимостью методов - то же самое, но есть нюанс с самой необходимостью тестировать приватные методы. Если `groupId` у вас является приватным свойством, то скорее всего тестировать надо не сам `groupId`, а тот публичный метод, который его использует (например, `SomeMethod`).

Этот вопрос подробно расписан в [C# - Как тестрировать private и protected методы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/321356/177221), со всеми за и против такого тестирования.