# Корректно ли специально для тестов объявлять классы в основном коде с модификатором public?

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты, namespace, mstest

Есть проект консольного приложения с библиотекой классов, находящихся в *namespace MyProject*;
Для тестирования кода в решение я добавил новый проект *MSTest Test Project* c *namespace MyProject.Test*;
В тестах проекта *MyProject.Test* я использую директиву *using MyProject*;
Соответственно, получаю доступ только к тем классам *MyProject*, которые с модификатором *public*.
Корректно ли специально для тестов объявлять классы в основном коде с модификатором *public*?
Как можно получить доступ к *private* классам *MyProject* с *MyProject.Test* другим способом (хотя наверное это невозможно..)
Как правильно поступать в таких случаях?
**Спасибо!**

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Тестирование кода уровня доступности internal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/455011/%d0%a2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d1%83%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-internal)

Comment: Если бы вы использовали подход TDD, то у вас бы естественным путем выделились бы публичные классы и методы покрытые тестами. Когда создание тестов происходит на существующем коде, то, пожалуй, лучше начинать с интеграционных тестов, а для их создания, вам придется прибегнуть к публичности каких-то методов и классов, тем самым ставшее публичным вы затем сможете покрыть модульными тестами.