# Дружественная сборка

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты, assembly

У меня есть 2 проекта в solution. В одном класс, где есть private методы, которые нужно протестировать. Другой проект это юнит тесты. Знаю, что я могу использовать механизм дружественных сборок, чтобы получить доступ к private методам того класса. Подскажите, как мне это сделать? Желательно, максимально подробно.

Comment: Приватные методы не нужно тестировать </thread>

Comment: Дубликат? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/208816/10105

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Юнит-тестами покрывается обычно публично видимая часть. Для тестов и для "пользователя" (программиста, использующего ваш api) класс является черным ящиком - что-то передается на вход, что-то получается на выходе, это и тестируется.

Если у вас вощникла потребность тестировать private методы, возможно, у вас нарушается принцип единой ответственности (single responsibility principle). Попробуйте выполнить декомпозицию, выделите дополнительный класс и сами обращайтесь к нему (и тестируйте его) по принципу черного ящика. 
А private члены - это его внутреннее состояние, которое не должно быть интересно за пределами этого класса.

Comment: «по принципу черного ящика» если речь о юнит-тестах, то это все-таки white-box-test. Если выделяется *внешняя* зависимость (внутри класса обращение к базе, сети, файловой системе и т.д.) но такой класс лучше протестировать на уровне интеграционных/системных/приёмочных тестах, а не на уровне юнит-тестов.

Comment: Да, согласен, скорее "белый ящик".