# Правильно ли использовать рефлексию при тестировании

Tags: тестирование, рефлексия

Разгорелся небольшой спор.

Правильно ли с помощью рефлексии получать значения приватных полей при модульном(и интеграционном) тестировании? Или необходимо менять дизайн класса под тест?

Подобный вопрос уже был на en SO, но только там речь шла о рефлексии в целом. Хочется услышать аргументированное мнение русского комьюнити. Если нет, то какие вы видите проблемы?

**UPD**
`Java` имеет в своем распоряжении механизм `package private`. Меняет ли это дело в "мире Java"?

**UPD 2**
Вот конкретный кейс. Есть некий класс - фабрика. Генерит классы. Среди прочих есть поле версии этой фабрики. Не версии всего приложения, а именно версия этой фабрики. Фабрика добавляет это поле в генерируемые классы. Это поле приватное и нигде больше не используется, кроме тестов. В тестах оно нужно, чтоб ассертнуть ожидаемый класс с сгенерированным.

Comment: приватные поля вообще не надо тестировать

Comment: @Grundy да, это понятно. Речь идет о получении значений приватного поля, чтоб использовать его в дальнейшем

Comment: Приватное поле потому и приватное, что используется _внутри_. Если оно должно использоваться снаружи, то это уже не приватное поле.

Comment: Класс предоставляет его пользователю некую полезную логику через интерфейс. Вот эту логику и этот интерфейс и нужно тестировать. Приватные поля и методы не доступны пользователю класса, поэтому не надо их тестировать. А если очень хочется, то стоит подумать над вопросом корректности интерфейса.

Comment: Вот конкретный кейс. Есть некий класс - фабрика. Генерит классы. Среди прочих есть поле версии этой фабрики. Не версии всего приложения, а именно версия этой фабрики. Фабрика добавляет это поле в генерируемые классы. Это поле приватное и нигде больше не используется, кроме тестов. В тестах оно нужно, чтоб ассертнуть ожидаемый класс с сгенерированным.

Comment: @MichaelBelyakov В моем примере тестируется публичный метод. Но публичный метод использует приватное поле. Результат публичного метода нужно с чем-то ассертнуть. Для этого нужно знать значение приватного поля

Comment: Не стоит ли добавить публичный метод getVersion()?

Comment: @MichaelBelyakov Ну так об этом собственно и вопрос :) `Или необходимо менять дизайн класса под тест?` - Вот конкретно вот эта часть

Comment: @Oleg имхо, раз инкапсуляция предназначена для скрытие магии от внешнего мира, то ни тесты, ни остальная часть внешнего мира не должна знать о ней. Можно внутри все поменять (глубокий рефакторинг), но реализовав публичный интерфейс все должно работать правильно, включая и тесты и внешний код.

Comment: Я правильно понял, что у вас может существовать несколько фабрик разных версий и вы хотите быть уверены, что конкретный класс создан конкретной версией фабрики? Я согласен с комментарием tcpack4, не стоит лишний раз лезть к закрытой части класса. Это делает ваши тесты хрупкими. Менять интерфейс под тесты тоже не правильно, но если возникает в этом необходимость, то видимо интерфейс спроектирован не корректно.

Comment: Почти. Фабрика будет эволюционировать. Будет расти версия в классах. Сама версия носит лишь информационный характер для человека, читающего экземпляр класса. (Сами экземпляры живут долго, могут пережить конкретную версию фабрики). Класс спроектирован корректно. Версия фабрики - специфичная информация для самой фабрики, и сокрыта. Вопрос в том, как корректно спроектировать тест?

Comment: @tcpack4 Как я писал уже, тестируется именно публичный метод. Однако данный метод использует в своей работе приватную информацию

Comment: Возможный дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/321346/10105, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/208710/10105

Comment: @VladD Спасибо за первый информативный комментарий. Однако в тех вопросах речь о тестировании приватных методов. У меня ситуация немного другая. Я тестирую публичный метод, который в своей работе использует(и выдает наружу) приватную информацию.

Comment: @Oleg: Ну, консенсус в тех ответах состоит в следующем: тестировать нужно соответствие поведения спецификации. А спецификация не может быть в терминах приватных переменных, она описывает поведение. Вот это поведение и нужно тестировать. Класс должен вести себя согласно спецификации, а как он этого добивается — его личные подробности. То есть доступ к приватным переменным не должен быть нужен.

Comment: @VladD В моем случае - самый правильный вариант - затереть поле с приватной информацией и ассертнуть без него? Правильно понимаю?

Comment: @Oleg: Давайте сначала. Какое требование из ТЗ вы тестируете? Насколько я понимаю, правильный тест _не имеет права_ знать о приватных полях/методах/...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67996/discussion-between-oleg-and-vladd).

Comment: В Spring  есть, к примеру, `ReflectionTestUtils` для моканья. Так что да, в некоторых случаях рефлексия для тестов - нормальная практика.