# Как правильно тестировать методы, использующие сокрытую информацию

Tags: тестирование, рефлексия

Ранее я уже писал [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/738693), который по всей видимости оказался слишком общим, поэтому не удалось получить конкретного ответа. Поэтому задаю новый, но конкретный вопрос.

Сразу оговорюсь, что код буду писать на Scala, но на подход к тестированию конкретный язык влияет минимально. Мой Scala код можно "читать на любом языке".

Итак, пусть есть простая модель `Person`, с полями `name` и `age`. И есть модель, использующая `Person` для неких целей, пусть будет `PersonExport`:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
case class PersonExport(version: String, date: DateTime, person: Person)
```

Есть сервис:

```
class PersonExportService {
  private val version = "v1"  //Тут версия - это специфическая информация для сервиса, и не используется никем, помимо самого сервиса, поэтому сокрыта. Несет исключительно информационный характер для людей, которые будут читать экспортированный Person

  def getPersonExport() = {
    val p = Person("Martin Odersky", 59)  // Допустим сходили тут в БД
    val pe = PersonExport(version, DateTime.now, p)

    return pe
  } 
}
```

Необходимо протестировать метод `getPersonExport`(`DateTime.now` мокнут и возвращает одинаковое время):

```
"Person" must {
  s"successfully exported" in {
    val version = ??? // Надо что-то делать тут
    val person = getPersonExport  // Фактический результат
    val p = PersonExport(version, DateTime.now, Person("Martin Odersky", 59))  // Ожидаемый результат

    p should equal(person)
  }
}
```

Сейчас тест не пройдет, так как будут расхождения в поле `version`.

Наконец, вопрос: **Что следует предпринять?**

1. Получить значение `version`, используя Рефлексию
2. Изменить дизайн класса под тест, нарушив сокрытие и добавить геттер
3. Затереть поле `version` и в ожидаемом и в фактическом результате и сравнивать без него
4. Другой вариант?
5. **UPD** Объявить тест в таком-же пакете как и сервис и воспользоваться механизмом `package-private`(Читать private поля из классов того-же пакета)

Comment: Тестировать всегда нужно чёрный ящик, публичный интерфейс. Ни к чему тестировать внутреннее сокрытое состояние.

Comment: @vp_arth `def getPersonExport()` вполне себе публичный

Comment: Ну так и тестируйте его заявленные свойства. По сути, достаточно проверить тип результата, остальное может варьироваться в real-life и от входных параметров никак не зависит.

Comment: Основная проблема тут: `p should equal(person)` - не нужно сравнивать объекты в лоб, проверяйте задекларированное поведение. `person.getPerson.getName should equal 'Martin Odersky'`

Comment: @vp_arth Конструктивно. Спасибо. Перепишите в ответ? Хоть плюсик поставлю

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Значение поля `version` в *ожидаемом* результате (`p`) должно быть специфицировано в ТЗ. То есть, в вашем тесте вы должны прописать `val version = "v1"`, опираясь на ТЗ.

Если ТЗ не налагает требований на значение `version`, то вам нужно сравнивать без учёта этого поля. В этом случае ТЗ должно выдвинуть требование на желаемый результат (просто `equals` не пройдёт), и вы просто кодируете в соответствии с этим требованием.

Comment: А почему не забрать просто значение через рефлексию?

Comment: @Oleg потому что вы тогда тестируете соответствие программы текущему состоянию в оперативной памяти, а не ее спецификации

Comment: @Oleg: Потому что тесты должны _в точности_ соответствовать ТЗ. А в ТЗ не должно быть написано «значения приватных полей X и Y должны совпадать», это не дело ТЗ знать о приватных полях.

Comment: @VladD ТЗ устное и звучит примерно так: "Посмотри там в тестах, чтоб все поля присутствовали". В результате правильный вариант - вариант №3, правильно понял?

Comment: @Oleg: Я бы потребовал формализовать ТЗ. Или если архитектору _некогда_ (им всегда _некогда_), взялся бы написать его сам, и там бы указал конкретное значение версии.